# Text Field Equality

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I've got a table foo with a text field bar in it.  On that table I've got an after update trigger that is basically the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_foo() 
RETURNS TRIGGER
SECURITY DEFINER
AS
$_$
DECLARE 
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' and NEW.bar = OLD.bar THEN
    return NEW;
  END IF;

  /* Do some stuff */

END
$_$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Then I do something like this:  `Update foo set bar = bar || '';`.

But it doesn't bail when the text values are equal.

My question is why wouldn't PostgreSQL 8.3, and specifically pl/PgSQL call them equal and bail out early?

*Disclaimer:  Table, field, and variable names have been changed from their original to allow for posting online.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It Would be because one of the values is a null.
and a null cannot be equal  to any other value,

So you will need to add the extra criteria

```
(New.bar is  null or Old.bar is null)
```

Or

```
  NEW.bar is not distinct from OLD.bar
```

Comment: Turns out I had a few NULL fields that were affecting this check for whether or not things changed in the significant fields.